# Angular 7 Http response

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular-httpclient

When in component I get a response from our Rest Api, but when I move the code over to a service it will not give a response with data.

This is the code in my component:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
nodes: any = [];
this.http.get('https://prokom-aimcms-dev.azurewebsites.net/api/contentapi/getall', {observe: 'response'})
          .subscribe(response => {
             this.nodes = response;
      });
```

This will give the response:

```
 {
  "headers": {
    "normalizedNames": {},
    "lazyUpdate": null,
    "lazyInit": null,
    "headers": {}
  },
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": "OK",
  "url": "someUrl",
  "ok": true,
  "type": 4,
  "body": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "contentId": "59f37a5c-b209-4813-a11b-0d2e34ec5530",
      "created": "2019-02-05T08:49:00.207078",
      "modified": "2019-02-21T13:02:19.2983893",
      "title": "TEst",
      "published": null,
      "creator": null,
      "state": 0,
      "sortIndex": 0,
      "contentObject": null,
      "metaObject": null,
      "parameterObject": null,
      "version": 0,
      "language": "nb_no",
      "parentContent": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "relatedContents": [
        "aa8e9c90-adbb-4853-98b9-53e431e27c4b"
      ],
      "tags": [],
      "categories": []
    },
.......
```

But if I move this over to a service (somename.service.ts):

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

public getAllNodes(): Observable<any> {
   return this.http.get('someURL', {observe: 'response'})
   .map(response => {
      return response;
});
```

}

And call it from the component (somename.component.ts)

```
this.nodes = this.aimService.getAllNodes().subscribe();
```

Then the response will be:

```
 {
  "closed": true,
  "_parent": null,
  "_parents": null,
  "_subscriptions": null,
  "syncErrorValue": null,
  "syncErrorThrown": false,
  "syncErrorThrowable": true,
  "isStopped": true,
  "_parentSubscription": null,
  "destination": {
    "closed": true,
    "_parent": null,
    "_parents": null,
    "_subscriptions": null,
    "syncErrorValue": null,
    "syncErrorThrown": false,
    "syncErrorThrowable": false,
    "isStopped": true,
    "_parentSubscription": null,
    "destination": {
      "closed": true
    },
    "_parentSubscriber": null,
    "_context": null
  }
}
```

Anyone know why this is so? And how I can get the data from the service as well.

Comment: Didn't you meant to observe the body instead the response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this.nodes = this.aimService.getAllNodes().subscribe();
```

What you're doing here is essentially assigning the value of the subscription to `this.nodes`

When you subscribe, you will be able to provide "callbacks", which is what you need to do, in order to access your data. As below:

```
this.aimService.getAllNodes().subscribe((data) =>
{
    // you'll see the expected data here
), (error) =>
{
    // if the request fails, this callback will be invoked
});
```

---

If you're new to `Observables`, and the realm of RXJS, I'd highly recommend going [here](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library)

Answer (score 3):

You should subscribe and assign the value coming from subscription:

```
this.aimService.getAllNodes().subscribe((response) => {

     this.node = response.data // or any value from the response object
 }, (err) => {
       console.log(error); // any error should be caught here
 });
```